# Series convergence of a fraction that tends to 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Which method allows me to calculate the value of the series as it tends to infinite?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{3^n} $$

Comment: It is a geometric series

Comment: Rewrite it to $\sum (\frac 23)^n$.

Comment: Direct calculation of partial sums + taking the limit, ratio test, root test are the first three that come to mind. In all honesty, I wouldn't look for a fourth one.

Comment: The sum of series is $\dfrac{a_1}{1-r}$ where $a_1$ is the first term.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we know that 
If $|x|<1$, using a known result on [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}.
\end{align}$$
Put $x=\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

A geometric series is defined by $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} r^n$.

If $|r| < 1$, the series is convergent and $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1 - r}$.

Rewrite you series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{2}{3})^n$. As $\frac{2}{3} < 1$, your series converges to $\frac{1}{1 - (\frac{2}{3})}$.